# var_dump and print_r displays different results - PHP

Tags: php

I have a string (JSON type), i wanted to convert it to PHP Array.

```
{  
   "action":"putEntity",
   "dataPacket":{  
      "entity":[  
         {  
            "name":"product",
            "data":[  
               {  }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I did following to do so,

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($data), True);
```

When i do **var_dump($array);** it displays:

```
string(1578) "{ "action": "putEntity", "dataPacket": { "entity": [{ "name": "product", "data": [{ }] }] } }"
```

But when i do, **print_r($array);** it displays:

```
{
   "action": "putEntity",
   "dataPacket":{
   "entity":[
         {
         "name": "product",
         "data":[{}]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Issue is when i try to print `$array['dataPacket'];` **it throws error illegal string offset 'dataPacket'**

why var_dump is showing it as String? please help.

Comment: Are you looping through the JSON array and then outputting it's results?

Comment: Are you... encoding the (already encoded) string and then decoding one layer, thus giving you back the original (encoded) string?

Comment: var_dump is showing it as a string as it is a string at that moment. If it is valid json you can decode it and then you can access $array['dataPacket']. Exact debugging is hard without your full code.

Comment: Actually, `print_r()` is also saying it's a string. If it were an array, its output would be along the lines of `Array ( [action] => putEntity` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($data), True);
```

Should be

```
$array = json_decode($data, true);
```